# Copy a text from excel and paste it in powerpoint, and then format the copied text

Tags: vb.net, excel, fonts, powerpoint

i am a very new to writing vb scripts. i am able to copy a text (or a range) from excel and paste it in powerpoint, and i would like to change the font size (to 12), put a border and set the background to white. below is what i have to copy the text from excel:

```
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Sub Copy_ExcelText_Powerpoint_and_Format()
' This copies a range in excel and copy it in Powerpoint, and then formats it
Dim PPApp As Object ' As PowerPoint.Application

' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J4").copy
PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=10, Link:=0

' now format the text
' .......

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i found some scripts that will change the font of all the text in the active slide, but i only want to change the font size (etc.) of the text that was just copied from excel. any help will be highly appreciated. many thanks!

may 3,2014 edit

hello, i've thought of a different approach, that instead of doing a paste, i would do a AddTextbox, but it is giving me a "Runtime Error 13 type Mismatch" error.

below is the modified script:
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Sub Copy_ExcelText_Powerpoint_and_Format()
    ' This copies a range in excel and copy it in Powerpoint, and then formats it
    Dim PPApp As Object ' As PowerPoint.Application

```
' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint          
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J4").copy  --commented out
'PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=10, Link:=0--commented out

' use addtextbox instead
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
        (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

With PPSlide
' create textbox
    Set tBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
             Left:=1, _
             Top:=250, _
             Width:=720, _
             Height:=100)

    ' set content
    tBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value

    ' Set format
    tBox.Font.Bold = False
    tBox.Font.Name = "Arial (Headings)"
    tBox.Font.Size = 12
    tBox.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
End With
```

appreciate any help i can get. thanks.

Comment: You don't mention what line the error occurs on.  Always best to say.  But most likely you want Set PPTSlide = PPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The error was on Set tBox = ....

Comment: I actually was able to solve the problem. The problem was on my variable declaration, originally it was:


Dim tBox As PowerPoint.Shape

by changing it to below, the error was gone:

Dim tBox As PowerPoint.Shape